# Integer solutions of $ z^3 y^2 = x(x-1)(x+1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, powerful-numbers

According to a conjecture there are no three
consecutive powerful numbers.

Necessary condition for this is integer solution of

$$ z^3 y^2 = x(x-1)(x+1) \qquad (1) $$

> What are integer solutions of (1)?

For fixed $z$ Weierstrass model is

$$ v^2 = u^3 - z^6 u$$

$x = u/z^3, y= v/z^6$. Since $z$ is integer $u,v$ must be integers
too.

Comment: Why are $u$ and $v$ integers? Can you give some reference or the proof?

Comment: If $x$ is even, then the three integers $x-1$, $x$ and $x+1$ are pairwise coprime, and the equation (1) is equivalent to wanting all of these to be square-full.  If $x$ is odd, then $(x-1)$ and $x+1$ have a common factor $2$.  Removing this common factor, we are led to ask if it is possible for $n$, $2n+1$, and $n+1$ all to be square-full.  The same heuristic that suggests that there are no three consecutive square-full numbers, also suggests that there are at most finitely many square-full triples $n$, $2n+1$, $n+1$ (and maybe there are none).

Comment: @GHfromMO I think they are integers because of the map from the Weierstrass model. x=u/z^3 <=> x z^3 = u

Comment: Since $x^2-1$ and $x$ are coprime, both would need to be powerful. Then the $abc$ triple $(1, x^2-1, x^2)$ would have to have quality $q\ge 2\log(x)/(\log(x^2-1)/2+\log(x)/2)>4/3$.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Indeed. But abc allows finitely many solutions.

Answer (score 3):

According to the conjecture of Schinzel and Tijdeman (Schinzel, Α., Tijdeman, R., On the equation $y^n = P(x)$, Acta Arith. 31 (1976), 199-204), if a polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients has at least three simple zeros, then the equation
$$
P(x) = y^2z^3
$$
has only finitely many solutions inintegers $x,y,z$ with $yz\neq 0$.

See also P. G. Walsh, On a conjecture of Schinzel and Tijdeman, in: Number Theory in Progress, Edited by: Kálmán Györy, Henryk Iwaniec and Jerzy Urbanowicz. De Gruyter 1999.

Comment: Thanks. You mean simple zeros over the complex numbers, right? And does this imply finitely many three consecutive powerfull numbers?

Comment: Yes, simple zeros over $\mathbb{C}$ and, again, yes, this conjecture implies that there are only finitely many consecutive powerfull numbers.

Comment: @MaciejUlas - you must mean finitely may triples, right? (Is there any reason to even expect finitely many pairs?)

Comment: @Yaakov, no, there is a reason to expect *infinitely* many pairs of consecutive powerful numbers: $8$ is the smaller element of such a pair, and, if $n$ is the smaller number of such a pair, then so is $4n(n+1)$.

Comment: Of course, I was thinking about three consecutive powerfull numbers but write consecutive powerfull numbers. Sorry for this.